# structure of finite polycyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

We know that every finite nilpotent group is written as a direct product of its Sylow subgroups.
My question is : can we write finite polycyclic groups as a direct product of some subgroups?
if the answer was yes then characterize those subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

No. $S_3$ is polycyclic, but indecomposable.